# checking database and validate form with angular

Tags: angularjs

I can use ajax to check infomation in database with jquery but I dont know do same with angularjs . I use

```
  $http({
            type : "post",
            dataType : "JSON",
            url : "register.php",
            data : data,
            success : function(result)
            {
....
}
```

php code

```
    $errors = array(
        'error' => 0
    );

    $username   = $_POST['username']
    $password   = $_POST['password']
    $email      =$_POST['email']
    $fullname   = $_POST['fullname']
    $sql = "SELECT * "
            . "FROM USERS "
            . "WHERE username='".$username."' "
                    . "OR email='".$email."'";
     if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        if ($row['username'] == $username){
            $errors['username'] = 'Tên đăng nhập đã tồn tại';
        }
        if ($row['email'] == $email){
            $errors['email'] = 'Email đã tồn tại';
        }
    }
    if (count($errors) > 1){
        $errors['error'] = 1;
        die (json_encode($errors));
    }else{
    //insert database
    }

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

but I dont know do next step . I want check in database if have user name show message error else show succes .Pls help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `success` is deprecated but you're on the right path. Here's how you would do it now:

```
 $http({
     type : "post",
     url : "register.php",
     data : data
 }).then(function(response){
     // If data is returned, do stuff with it here
     console.log('Yay, my data was POSTed', response.data);
 }, function(response){
     console.log('Aww, it failed.');
 });
```

It would be easier to help you further, if you add a bit more information on what you're actually trying to achieve. For instance what is returned by this "register.php" endpoint, and what you intent to do after this.

Comment: I want check if have username in database show error and dont have show success

Comment: You can check this as a part of the `register.php` code server-side and in case of error, return a 400 Bad Request error including the error message in the response body. That error message would be caught by the failure callback and you can show it to the user then. How do you intent to show this to the user? As a message in the view or some sort of alert/toast popup? Could you share a bit more of your code?

Comment: i' edited the question and add more code . Could you please refer to the specific example

Answer (score 0):

check the [DOC](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) for `$http`.

> The $http service is a function which takes a single argument — a configuration object — that is used to generate an HTTP request and returns a promise.

The response comes under promise `(.then)`.

```
$http({
   type : "POST", 
   url : "register.php",
   data : data,
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available/success 
    console.log(response.data)
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
    console.log(response.data)
  });
```